# Load javascript of plugin into home page

Tags: php, wordpress

i have site and i will programming a plugin that add and update record in data base.

my problem is i use JavaScript in plugin file but its show in home page and its show problem.

how can i don't show this JavaScript code in home page and show only in plugin page in admin file .

this is plugin code:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//start autocomplate
         var availableTags = [
            <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM web_categories");
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo '"'.$rows['type'].'",';
            }
            echo '""';
            ?>
        ];      
$("#type_1").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
// end autocomplate
//start autocomplate
         var availableTags = [
            <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM web_categories");
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo '"'.$rows['type'].'",';
            }
            echo '""';
            ?>
        ];      
$("#type_11").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
// end autocomplate
//start autocomplate
         var availableTags = [
            <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM web_categories");
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo '"'.$rows['type'].'",';
            }
            echo '""';
            ?>
        ];      
$("#type_2").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
// end autocomplate
//start autocomplate
         var availableTags = [
            <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM web_categories");
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo '"'.$rows['type'].'",';
            }
            echo '""';
            ?>
        ];      
$("#type_3").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
// end autocomplate
});
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of selecting x times the same resultset, why not just select 1 resultset into a variable? Think of your  users server performance.. Also this looks like x times the same autocomplete? Why not apply it to a class then instead of an id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, you want to add the js only in plugins admin page, then you can use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script),something like

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_admin_menu');
function plugin_admin_menu() {
      add_options_page('Plugin Admin Page', 'Plugin Admin Page', 10, 'plugin-admin-page', 'plugin_admin_page');
}    
add_action('admin_print_scripts-settings_page_plugin-admin-page', 'add_my_scripts');
function add_my_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script('pluginscript', plugins_url('/js/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}
```